# How to check the number of Reblogs Per User on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Is it possible to see the number of reblogs per user anywhere in the Tumblr dashboard? I only see one entry per user when I click on 'notes', like 'privid reblogged this', but not the number of times he reblogged this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to look at the amount of reblogs per different user anywhere in the Tumblr dashboard?

No, I don't think so.

It might work with their API, but that wouldn't be displayed in the dashboard.

> I only see one entry per user when I click on 'notes', like 'privid reblogged this', but not the amount of times he reblogged this.

I think when a user reblogs the same post again, he would be listed two times in the Notes list (it's sorted chronologically).

---

Partly related: [Check if I already reblogged a post?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31015/check-if-i-already-reblogged-a-post)