# Check if I already reblogged a post?

Tags: tumblr

I want to curate a special topic on my Tumblr, so I'm trying to reblog everything related. After months and hundreds of posts, it's hard to know if I reblogged something already.

Because I don't want to duplicate a reblog, I check if my Tumblr is listed in the "Notes" list of a post. Unfortunately, this list can become very long and I'd have to click "Show more notes" and on each page search for my name.

**Is there an easier way to check if I already reblogged a post?**

If not as a function in Tumblr itself, maybe with a 3rd-party service or with a custom API call (so I could built a service myself, if it is easy)?

(It's not my main blog but a sub-blog, if it matters.)

Comment: If your posts comprise mainly of photos, then you can try my newly released [**Deja Vu for Tumblr**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deja-vu-for-tumblr/ipbbjejdpjjbedjmjcgdhldgbdbfhdol) Chrome extension. I developed this because I've long been annoyed at having duplicate photos and wanted to weed out all the duplicates from my 2200+ posts.

Answer (score 4):

What I am thinking of doing is liking everything I have on my blog, then if something on your dash is liked you know you have posted it already

Comment: Thanks! It’s a workaround that would certainly work for some, but not for me (because I’m using this Favorite functionality extensively already for other use-cases).

Answer (score -4):

Use the search engine on your tumblr page. Search for the original sourse's name.