# Prevent posting duplicate photos to my blog

Tags: tumblr

I have a photo blog with thousands of posts on Tumblr. When posting a photo, how can I make sure I haven't already seen it somewhere and posted it sometime?

Comment: Related (no duplicate): [Check if I already reblogged a post?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31015/24166)

Answer (score 2):

You might use Google image search with the image you're looking to post and limit results to your blog with the `site:example.com` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I do to no avail: I right-click on the image >> select _Search Google for this image_ >> add _site:myBlog.tumblr.com_ to the search field.

Answer (score 1):

You can now easily find duplicate photos in your Tumblr blog by using this Chrome extension:

[**Deja Vu for Tumblr**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deja-vu-for-tumblr/ipbbjejdpjjbedjmjcgdhldgbdbfhdol)

Right now it can only detect duplicates in your posts, so you'll have to post the photo first. To keep your blog free of duplicates, you can scan weekly or monthly.

This extension is based on the open source [pHash](http://www.phash.org/) perceptual hash fingerprinting library, which allows you to detect duplicates with surprising accuracy without installing a dedicated desktop application.

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [XKit](http://xkit.info/). It is a set of browser extensions for Tumblr that adds / modifies behavior of the site.

[On an update on Oct 30, 2013](http://xkit-extension.tumblr.com/post/65552576133/xkit-update-october-30), the developer added a feature to recognize already-re logged posts.

> **One-Click Postage**
>
> Added option to hide posts already reblogged / drafted / queued using One-Click Postage on the dashboard.

If you're in mobile you may want to consider [XKit mobile](http://www.xkitm.com/)

Please note, however, that the extension is not officially from Tumblr and that it occasionally breaks when Tumblr updates its UI/API. It is generally fixed right away but there's no guarantee that will keep being the case, since it's a side-project for a single developer.